# WPF Displaying 3D object in original colour

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I have displayed the 3D object  by referring the following Link 
 [Display 3D Model using Window Presentation Foundation](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/882885/Display-D-Model-using-Window-Presentation-Foundat?msg=5583429#xx5583429xx)
.Everything is working fine except the object is displaying in plain blue.can any one help me out to display it in the original color?.
 [This](https://helixtoolkit.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/1173-model-showing-blue-color)   link is referred  but still no go.Any help is appreciated.

My code is like

```
namespace Display3DModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //Path to the model file
        private const string MODEL_PATH = "Model/Model2.obj";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ModelVisual3D device3D = new ModelVisual3D();
            device3D.Content = Display3d(MODEL_PATH);
            // Add to view port
            viewPort3d.Children.Add(device3D);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display 3D Model
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">Path to the Model file</param>
        /// <returns>3D Model Content</returns>
        private Model3D Display3d(string model)
        {
            Model3D device = null;
            try
            {
                //Adding a gesture here
                viewPort3d.RotateGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);

                //Import 3D model file
                ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();

                //Load the 3D model file
                device = import.Load(model);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle exception in case can not file 3D model
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Error : " + e.StackTrace);
            }
            return device;
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Display3DModel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort3d" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="true" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
            <!-- Remember to add light to the scene -->
            <helix:DefaultLights/>
        </helix:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: All depends on your code, the model and the material. The question does not contain any of these. Please add them or close the question.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Hi I have added the code.The Model is opening properly in the 3D viewer in Windows 10.

Comment: Please check the obj file and see if it refers to a mtl file and if the mtl file is available for the program: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324748/how-to-load-textures-and-materials-using-helix-toolkit